# Performance of an ProgressBar when Visibility is Collapsed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ProgressBar with ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate=True to notify the user of ongoing operations.
The way I use it now I display it with Visibility=Visible and hide it with Collapsed.

Now my question is: Will WPF stop rendering completely or will I still have some power going into animating the ProgressBar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will stop rendering as far as i know. You can run a stress test by putting *n* progress bars in a dialog, the CPU load should be heavy if they are `Visible` and gone completely when `Collapsed`.

Comment: Just tried it: CPU usage starts off high when `Collapsed` but goes down after a few seconds. (Used about 100 ProgressBars)